# Treating different sql values into the same group

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a gender table. For genders other than male and female, the default value would be `'other'` but due to some errors, the database has some users with gender value = `null`. So instead of changing the data directly. Is there a query to get the other and null values as the same type.

```
id |  username | gender
 1 |   mark    | male
 2 |  samantha | female
 3 |  rupert   | other 
 4 |  collins  | null

$genders = User::whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->select([
        'gender', 
        DB::raw('count(*) as total')
    ])
    ->groupBy('gender')
    ->get();
```

the query above gives 4 labels `['male','female','other','null']`. Is there a way to get 3 labels instead `['male','female','other']` and treat the null values the same as the other value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with a `DB::raw` query, I think. Please try this one:

```
$genders = User::whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->select([
            DB::raw('case when gender is null then \'other\' else gender end as gender'), 
            DB::raw('count(*) as total')
        ])
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('case when gender is null then \'other\' else gender end'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: this changes the null data to other. but for the grouping it still creates an extra group

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You need to change the `groupby` as well. Please try my updated code.